# "java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: utf8mb4" error in retrofit

Tags: android, json, character-encoding, gson, retrofit2

> 10-26 23:29:25.422 30062-30062/okok.com.retrofittrial W/System.err:
>   java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: utf8mb4 10-26
>   23:29:25.422 30062-30062/okok.com.retrofittrial W/System.err:     at
>   java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:571) 10-26 23:29:25.422
>   30062-30062/okok.com.retrofittrial W/System.err:     at
>   okhttp3.MediaType.charset(MediaType.java:103) 10-26 23:29:25.422
>   30062-30062/okok.com.retrofittrial W/System.err:     at
>   okhttp3.ResponseBody.charset(ResponseBody.java:114) 10-26 23:29:25.422
>   30062-30062/okok.com.retrofittrial W/System.err:     at
>   okhttp3.ResponseBody.charStream(ResponseBody.java:100) 10-26
>   23:29:25.422 30062-30062/okok.com.retrofittrial W/System.err:     at
>   retrofit2.converter.jackson.JacksonResponseBodyConverter.convert(JacksonResponseBodyConverter.java:32)
>   10-26 23:29:25.422 30062-30062/okok.com.retrofittrial W/System.err:
>   at
>   retrofit2.converter.jackson.JacksonResponseBodyConverter.convert(JacksonResponseBodyConverter.java:23)
>   10-26 23:29:25.422 30062-30062/okok.com.retrofittrial W/System.err:
>   at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:213) 10-26
>   23:29:25.422 30062-30062/okok.com.retrofittrial W/System.err:     at
>   retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:109) 10-26
>   23:29:25.422 30062-30062/okok.com.retrofittrial W/System.err:     at
>   okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:133) 10-26
>   23:29:25.422 30062-30062/okok.com.retrofittrial W/System.err:     at
>   okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33) 10-26
>   23:29:25.422 30062-30062/okok.com.retrofittrial W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>   10-26 23:29:25.422 30062-30062/okok.com.retrofittrial W/System.err:
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>   10-26 23:29:25.422 30062-30062/okok.com.retrofittrial W/System.err:
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 10-26 23:31:32.307
>   30062-30069/okok.com.retrofittrial W/art: Suspending all threads took:
>   6.975ms

My json response 's content type is

> application/json;  charset=utf8mb4

i am able to send request ,and get response ,but it seems response is not getting parsed. I do not get response in my retrofit callback.

In debugging i can see my response ,but not in retrofit callback

Comment: `charset=utf8mb4` is a charset that is not supported. not much you can do if you can't change the charset the server sends.

Comment: i can't change server response