# Android Response: java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: utf8mb4

Tags: java, android, encoding, decoding

I got this error:

```
java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: utf8mb4
```

And I haven't found any solutions yet.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40269364/java-nio-charset-unsupportedcharsetexception-utf8mb4-error-in-retrofit) says that there's no point to solve this problem, as long as, I can't I change the server side.

How can I handle this charset?

Comment: This charset is just utf8 which some idiot decided to call utf8mb4 instead in whatever context you're dealing with it. You can safely treat the charset as flat-out utf8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's My solution,

This decodes the response.body() into `UTF-8`:

```
String responseResult = null;
try {
    Log.d(TAG, response.body().contentType()+"");
    BufferedSource source = response.body().source();
    source.request(Long.MAX_VALUE); // Buffer the entire body.
    Buffer buffer = source.buffer();
    responseResult = buffer.clone().readString(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    Log.d(TAG, "result: "+responseResult);
}catch(Exception e){
    // TODO
}
```

However, the bigger problem was the URL was incorrect. If it's wrong URL, you can get this error.

For instance,

The URL must be `example.com/feed/4` but you sending the request to `example.com/feed`.

In my case, after decoding the body, I got `404 ERROR`. And then, realized the URL was wrong. So, I fixed and It worked fine!

The decode might not convert properly, for example, emojis. Then, try it without converting the body. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your database or run:

`ALTER DATABASE yourdatabasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`

If you can't change nothing on your backend service, try to change your charset configuration on your request like here:

[How to suppress Charset being automatically added to Content-Type in okhttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560601/how-to-suppress-charset-being-automatically-added-to-content-type-in-okhttp)

Comment: I can't change the server. And I guess the server needs utf8mb4.

Comment: are you using a cloud service? Is it possible to raise this problem as a dependency? give us more details about ur backend

Comment: I don't know about the backend. I am working on frontend. And I just got that format.

Comment: I don't know how you doing your request but probably you may have to change something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560601/how-to-suppress-charset-being-automatically-added-to-content-type-in-okhttp

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know how to use them... Can you give me some examples?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188363/discussion-between-chanjung-kim-and-igor-maia-romcy).